# Python Flask : IO Exception thrown from InvokeHTTP. Java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)

Tags: python, flask, apache-nifi

I have python script which is being called using python flask api from NiFi (Invokehttp prcoessor). I get below error sometime (Not always)

```
IO Exception thrown from InvokeHTTP. Java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
```

Here is my main.py

```
@app.route('/Customertax', methods = ['GET', 'POST'] )
def Customer_tax_main_f():
    outpath = Customer_tax.Customer_tax_f(request.data) 
    return send_file(outpath,"application/text")
```

Here is my .py code which has main processing

```
def Customer_tax_f(file):
    other processing logic
```

Comment: Were you able to track down the cause of the issue? I have run into a similar log message from Java.